# Groovy subcollection

Tags: collections, groovy

What is the Groovy way to get collection items without items in subcollection. For example:

collection:
[1,2,3,4,5,6]

subcollection:
[1,5,6]

the result should be:
[2,3,4]

EDIT:
It looks I'm doing something wrong. This is part of my code:

```
    def report = Report.get(params.report.id)
    def user = User.get(params.user.id)
    List<User> availableUsers = []
    availableUsers = User.findAllByCompany(company))

    List<User> addedUsers = []
    addedUsers = (List<User>) session["addedUsers"] ?: []
    addedUsers << user
    session["addedUsers"] = null
    session["addedUsers"] = addedUsers

    availableUsers = availableUsers - addedUsers
```

This code is only removing last user in addedUsers list.

**availableUsers: [John, Jack, Jim]**

**addedUsers: [John, Jack]**

**availableUsers - addedUsers: [John, Jim]**

Every time only the last item in addedUsers gets removed. I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious but I cant find it.

Comment: addedUsers is empty; I don't understand what you're trying to say. Collection subtraction works, so I suspect an issue with the data you're not divulging.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've edited my question. This is the whole code.

Comment: You're storing domain objects in the `session`?  That doesn't sound like a terribly good idea.

Comment: @tim_yates I know it isn't but I could't solve it differently. I could store id's of objects, but thats the only thing I could do for now. Can you find the problem otherwise?

Comment: My guess is that the objects from the session have changed in some way from those loaded by the Gorm (probably because they aren't from the same transaction or something).  Therefore, the only one that gets removed is the one you just loaded from the database (when removing them from a list you just loaded from the database as well).  I would either represent this in the domain model, or store ids in the session and load the users for them when required... Try: `addedUsers = session["addedUsers"].collect { User.get( it.id ) } ?: []`

Comment: @tim_yates Like I said the problem was obvious :) You were right - object from the session have changed so when I've used ids everything worked. Thanks! Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @drago done :-)  Glad we found the problem :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the obvious:

```
result = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] - [ 1, 5, 6 ]
```

Because that is what works...

#### Edit

Storing domain object in the session will result in the object being different between hibernate transactions, better to store the id in the session and get the Users fresh each time (or write this functionality into the domain if it needs persisting), something like:

```
addedUsers = session["addedUsers"].collect { User.get( it.id ) } ?: []
```